# Monitoring network connections in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a program I'm using on some relatively incompetent people that is designed to hand hold them through completely mundane and simple tasks of computer usage.  Basically what happens is they have to start a Verizon Card for internet, then establish a VPN connection, start a transport tool, and log into an application that dispatch uses to assign work orders to their computer.  The tool I'm writing currently has a step by step button popup that tells them what to do. I'm adding additional functionality now that will make this process even dumber so that they don't freak out when out in the field if something fails.  The first update I'm making is as follows:

Step one starts VZAccess Manager and then turns the button green when it's started.  I've added code that tests to see if the connection is up; when the connection is up it turns the button green with a popup that says the connection is established, when the connection goes down the button turns red and a popup saying the connection is down let's them know that's the issue with connectivity. Now what I would like to do is use this same idea to detect if the VPN connection is up.  Here is the code I'm using now:

(Actual function to test the connection)

```
private void AvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsAvailable)
        {
            Step1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            MessageBox.Show("YIPPIE!!!!" + "\n" + "VZWireless connection reestablished!");
        }
        else
        {
            Step1.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
            MessageBox.Show("OH NOES!!!!" + "\n" + "VZWireless connection disconnected!");
        }
    }
```

(Button click functions: 1 is for the VZ card, 2 is for VPN)

```
private void Step1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += AvailabilityChanged;
        Step1.Enabled = false;
        Step1.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
        Step1.Text = "Please Wait...";
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string strVsWireless = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Verizon Wireless\\VZAccess Manager\\VZAccess Manager.exe";
            Process VsWireless = Process.Start(strVsWireless);
            VsWireless.WaitForInputIdle();
        })
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Step1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            Step1.Text = "VZAccess Manager";
            Step2.Visible = true;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private void Step2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Step2.Enabled = false;
        Step2.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
        Step2.Text = "Please Wait...";
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string strCisco = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Cisco\\Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client\\vpnui.exe";
            Process Cisco = Process.Start(strCisco);
            Cisco.WaitForInputIdle();
        })
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Step2.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            Step2.Text = "Cisco VPN Client";
            Step3.Visible = true;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to either use my current function to expand for usage on the vpn connection, or just make another function for the vpn connection altogether.  I don't really care which, but I would appreciate efficiency.  The big thing I can't figure out is how to detect the VPN connection specifically.  The VPN connection is named "Cisco AnyConnection VPN Client".  Any idea's on how I can actively monitor this connection just like I'm monitoring the wireless card's connection?  On a side note, is there any way I can test if it's the first time establishing the connection so that it doesn't show the alert box the first time it connects, only if it gets disconnected first?

Comment: Have you checked the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client COM [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect23/administration/23admin1.html)?

Comment: No, does that actually have information for using C# to manipulate and monitor the Cisco application?  If I can actually fill in forms and stuff on top of what I'm currently doing that would be awesome.

Comment: C# can interact with any unmanaged code via Interop http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: The documentation ([here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect23/release/notes/anyconnect23rn.html)) talks about an API Package that provides examples to develop your own application to interact with Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client. If you got access to this package, its possible that would be helpful for you.

Comment: So that "kind of" helps me out, the only thing is there is nothing on Cisco's site about checking specific network information in C#.net.  I'm still having a problem with having the .net app checking the "Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client Connection" connection just like I'm doing above with the internet network connection.